# Replacing NaN value with zero, but zero is a value in angular data. Cannot replace NaN with other value either. Best workaround?

Tags: python, deep-learning, data-preprocessing

Issue I'm trying to solve has to do with data representation/preprocessing. I have a 2-D numpy array which has been populated with angle values between the interval [ 0 , 2pi ]. Only problem is, there are alot of instances of NaN values which I replaced with the value of 0.

In the end, i plan to use this data in a deep learning network, so you can imagine the issue this is causing during learning. The representative value of the NaN (the zero) is unfortunately equivilent to the angles 0 and 2pi. I can't just choose any other value for the NaN as this can become representative of an angle in my loss function as well.

Currently, I'm using the following loss: 2-2*cos(AngleGroundTruth-AnglePredict).

I would appreciate any advice in tackling this problem.

Edit: The spatial positions in the 2-D matrix matter, so I can't just remove the NaNs and resize the matrix. This importance on the spatial positions is why I replaced the NaNs with zero

Comment: If you are getting NaNs from some other piece of software, that piece is broken and you need to fix it. Not replace NaNs with something else.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Hmmm. Thing is, i am inserting the NaN values in areas in the ground truth data where I know that there is near zero probability of an angle. Keeping the original unlikely angle would insert too much randomness in the model. This is why I replace those values non-probable values with NaN and later on with zero. I also want to keep the spatial information intact, hence the zeros.

Comment: "zero probability of an angle" I don't understand what this means. If the intent is to indicate that uncertainty is too high,  why not output the angle *and* the uncertainty and let the consumer of the data decide what to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Where are these `NaN` values coming from in the first place? If you don't want them in your data, why don't you remove them instead of replacing them with `0`?

You can filter a numpy array like so. Notice that we are keeping all elements that are not `NaN`:

```py
import math
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([0, 3.14, float("NaN"), 1.83, 6.28])

filter_arr = []

for element in arr:
    filter_arr.append(!math.isnan(element))

newarr = arr[filter_arr]

print(filter_arr)
print(newarr)
```

Articles for reference:

- https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy/numpy_array_filter.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_math_isnan.asp

Comment: Hmm unfortunately I can't just remove the values. The spatial positions in the 2-D matrix matter, so I can't just remove the NaNs and resize the matrix. This importance on the spatial positions is why I replaced the NaNs with zero